# Spring boot - disable Liquibase at startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I want to have **Liquibase** configured with my **Spring Boot** application, so I added dependencies to `pom.xml` and set the path to `master.xml` in `application.properties`. This works fine and **Spring Boot** runs **Liquibase** at startup. The problem is that now I want to run **Liquibase** manually, not at startup of application. Should I completely disable auto-configuration for **Liquibase** or can I use it and only disable running evaluations at startup?

Comment: How will you run Liquibase Manually?

Answer (score 121):

The relevant property name has changed between Spring versions:

- For **Spring 4.x.x**: the `liquibase.enabled=false` application property disables Liquibase.
- For **Spring 5.x.x**: the `spring.liquibase.enabled=false` application property disables Liquibase.

---

P.S. And for Flyway:

- **Spring 4.x.x**: `flyway.enabled=false`
- **Spring 5.x.x**: `spring.flyway.enabled=false`

Answer (score 38):

Add `liquibase.enabled=false` in your application.properties file

[Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

But if you don't want to use liquibase from application anymore, remove liquibase starter altogether from pom.

Comment: This property was migrated to `spring.liquibase.enabled`.

Answer (score 35):

If you see on the LiquibaseProperties, there is a prefix like

```
 prefix = "spring.liquibase"
```

So, My suggestion is to use

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
```

It solved my problem with spring boot 2.0.0.RC1

Comment: spring.liquibase.enabled=false solved my problem too Spring 2.7.1

Answer (score 18):

I faced an issue where I wasn't able to disable Liquibase from properties for some reason, so this is how I disabled Liquibase with `@Bean` annotation:

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
  SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
  liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
  return liquibase;
}
```

Comment: After this I've received `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'liquibase' available`

Comment: This worked for me.  It is the only solution that makes a SpringLiquibase bean available for autowiring without running on startup. Remember to put it in a @Configuration class.

Answer (score 16):

There is one more programmatic approach.

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class)`

on Application main class

Answer (score 4):

Another approach for `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run Liquibase manually, you could use the liquibase maven plugin. Just add something like this to your pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <changeLogFile>src/main/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
      <propertyFile>src/main/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
      <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You can take a look at the [plugin documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/) for the configuration details.

And don't use the liquibase support from Spring Boot, as it is only meant to be used in runtime. Just remove the liquibase starter and/or any related dependencies as you'll only need the maven plugin.

Comment: The problem with this is that when spring boot finds liquibase on the classpath it will try to execute on startup afaik.

Comment: That's why you have to remove the liquibase starter, or any direct liquibase dependency if you added any. If you only have the liquibase maven plugin, liquibase is not in the application classpath.

Comment: If you disable it during the startup, how will we trigger to run the DB scripts which need to be run ?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the documented Spring Boot solution is `spring.liquibase.enabled=false`, it didn't work for me. To disable liquibase you can also use the following property:

```
liquibase.shouldRun=false
```

I passed this as a command line parameter when launching the Spring Boot jar

```
-Dliquibase.shouldRun=false
```

see https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/should-run.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spring.liquibase.enabled=true/false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application-{profile}.yml, you can use:

```
liquibase:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).