# conflict with liquibase maven plugin and spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I have setup a spring boot project (parent) with 3 modules inside.

```
-- parent
  --module 1
  --module 2
  --module 3
```

Now i would like to add a new maven project as a new module to this parent project.

The new maven project is using the **liquibase-maven-plugin** and works perfect as a single project. But when i try to integrate the new maven project to the parent project it fails.

```
Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default) 
on project database-migration: Error setting up or running Liquibase: 
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
Connection could not be created to ${database.url} with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  
Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

The liquibase-maven-plugin is not able anymore to replace the placeholder `${database.url}` definied in the `liquibase.properties` file, when i add this parent section to my new module project:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>backend-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

The parent / super POM looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>backend-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<modules>
  <module>api</module>
  <module>db</module>
  <module>business</module>
  <module>migration</module>
</modules>

<properties>
  <java.version>9</java.version>
  <start-class>xyz.Application</start-class>
  <postgresql.version>42.2.1</postgresql.version>
  <h2.database.version>1.4.197</h2.database.version>
  ...
</<properties>
<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>${lombok.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The new module POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>backend-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>migration</artifactId>

<properties>
    <liquibase.maven.plugin.version>3.5.3</liquibase.maven.plugin.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.2.1</postgresql.version>
    <env>local</env>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>update-db</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/filters/${env}/database.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/liquibase/</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>true</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                        <logging>debug</logging>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

in liquibase.properties

```
url: ${database.url}
username: ${database.username}
verbose: true
contexts: ${environment}
```

As i said works fine without the parent section in the new module POM.
I use this cmd to build the migration.

```
mvn clean install -Pupdate-db -Denv=local
```

I did tried serveral workarounds described here:

- [Spring boot - disable Liquibase at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708145/spring-boot-disable-liquibase-at-startup)
- [configure dataSource for liquibase in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491234/configure-datasource-for-liquibase-in-spring-boot?rq=1)

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: What's the extension of "liquibase property"? Because the placeholder that you are using, here doesn't work...

Comment: @rios0rios0 sorry, the filename is liquibase.properties